# How to find and average based on the neighbor's value

Tags: vba, excel

I was preparing an excel workbook to keep the progress of my studying, there are three different kinds of data (skill scores) and I would like to have an average of each kind. For example, for the skill A, there are many scores in that sheet and I need to find them and calculate the average, the way they can be found is based on their neighbor's value eg: (cell a): skill 1, (cell b): 17

Any idea how could it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AverageIf()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"skill 1",B:B)
```

If you want multiple criteria than look into the [AVERAGEIFS()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690)